# How to get redirecting url link with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, redirect

Say a website like www.example.com/random redirects you to a random website when you go there, I want to get the link it redirects to

I'm pretty much just looking for how http://redirectdetective.com/ works, in JavaScript

I'm sure the answer's already all over the place, but I'm not sure what this would be called so I don't know what to google, and all the answers I'm finding is in different languages I can't translate, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From http://redirectdetective.com/ i tried a url say http://blogspot.com/ .

First i curl here

```
curl http://blogspot.com/ --verbose
```

it gives me a bunch of detail, of which the interesting part is the **[HTTP RESPONSE HEADER](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/header)**.

```
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Location: http://www.blogger.com/
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Date: Tue, 13 Mar 2018 16:39:03 GMT
< Expires: Thu, 12 Apr 2018 16:39:03 GMT
< Server: sffe
< Content-Length: 220
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< Cache-Control: public, max-age=2592000
< Age: 1681577
```

then trying again with the `Location` parameter

```
curl http://www.blogger.com/ --verbose
```

giving me the response header

```
< HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
< P3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See https://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=151657 for more info."
< Location: https://www.blogger.com/
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Date: Mon, 02 Apr 2018 03:48:49 GMT
< Expires: Mon, 02 Apr 2018 03:48:49 GMT
< Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< Server: GSE
< Accept-Ranges: none
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

Iterating this way, you are surely going to reach the endpoint which actually serves your request.

Answer (score 0):

It is fetching the URL, and every time the response is another redirect, it fetches that new URL, etc. until it finally arrives at a non-redirected URL.

Answer (score 0):

In broad strokes: send a GET request to the URL, perhaps using AJAX, and upon receiving a 301 REDIRECT, look at the new URL that it sends back to redirect to.